# how to write raw like query in django2?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I was trying to develop a search application where a user can search and for my system requirement I need to **avoid ORM query** when I try to write this following raw query

```
q = request.POST.get('searchData')
    if q:
        titleInfo = Item.objects.raw("""select * from item where title like '%%s%'""", [q])
```

It gives me this error

```
ValueError at /test
unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 41
```

And if I remove the quotation

```
"""select * from item where title like %%s%"""
```

It gives me the following error

```
ValueError at /test
incomplete format
```

Where my query is working fine in MySQL database

Comment: You should explain *why* you need to avoid the orm, since thisb is trivial to express in it.

Comment: my database is not following foreign key system I use to act like foreign key system more over my query is not finished yet it's just a sample and also I'm a big fan of raw query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solve the problem like this**

```
q = request.POST.get('searchData')
    query = '%'+q+'%'
    if q:
        titleInfo = Item.objects.raw("select * from item where title like %s", [query])
```